# Отслеживание процессов vds

Tags: php, веб-сервер, vps

**Дано**:
  ВДС, процессор загружен на 97%, около 10 процесов, в среднем каждый занимает 10%, все связаны с php. - информацию взял через ssh - команда top.

Вопрос: каким макаром мне узнать детально информацию по каждому процессу, что бы понять какие php файлы изучать.

Comment: Интернет магазин, работает на вебасисте. 
На этой вдс-ке лежит 2 месяца как. Раньше проблем не было -- последние 5 дней наблюдаю тормоза, что удивительно - в определенное время суток. 

В среднем 1500 уников в сутки.

При этом особого увеличения количества посетителей сайта нет - данные беру из яндекс метрики.

Comment: Оперативка пропорционально процессору тоже увеличивается, если обычно около 512 мб, то в момент тормозов 750. Вообще на вдс-ке стоит 1024 мб оперативки.

А вообще обычно сайт летает, отдача страницы менее 1-й секунды.

Есть ли вероятность что хостер подселил на сервер соседа, который дает создает большую нагрузку - и это отображается на моем сайте?

Answer (score 1):

А как на счет оперативной памяти? Также не указано что у Вас за скрипты, что создают такую нагрузку. Возможно даже есть проблема с самим сервером (его настройкой).

Как один из вариантов, если скрипт не слишком большой, можно проверить части его исполнения с помощью засечки времени (функция microtime), тогда можно понять что выполняется слишком долго.

[Документация про функцию microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)